# ¿Por qué tengo esta advertencia?

Tags: c#

Tengo dos formularios, en el primero, he declarado una variable int que debe filtrar el día de una lista DateTime, por ejemplo, "Obtener todas las fechas que están en miércoles". Este int se llama WednesdayTotal.

En form1, puse una etiqueta y cambié su texto por WednesdayTotal.value, muestra "2", y quiero usar ese valor en el form 2 , por lo que el modificador de WednesdayTotal es públic , (porque es solo una prueba en este momento), y cuando quise usarlo, muestra 0. ¿Por qué?

Código Form1/HomeForm:

```
    public int WednesdayTotal;    
    WednesdayTotal = DateList.Count(x =>              x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
Código Form2:
    if (Home.WednesdayTotal >= 1)
    {
    WednesdayPin.Visible = true;
    WednesdayValue.Visible = true;
    WednesdayValue.Text =                Home.WednesdayTotal.ToString();
}
```

En la siguiente línea

```
WednesdayValue.Text =           Home.WednesdayTotal.ToString();
```

Muestra el error:

> Warning CS1690 Accessing a member on Form1.WednesdayTotal may cause a
>   runtime exception because it is a field of a marshal-by-reference
>   class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa advertencia informa que tu variable definida de forma pública es un campo y no una propiedad. Debes declararlo de la siguiente forma, declarando una propiedad de tu formulario

```
public int WednesdayTotal { get; set; }
```